# Sign In using firebase cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to make authentication using HTTP Requests (Firebase Cloud Fucntions) I implemented a HTTP function for the sign up so I send the information to my HTTP API with the POST method and with the Admin SDK I create A new User and I send back a JSON response but I didn't find any way to make login

What I want is to send email and password via HTTP Post and If the user exists and the data is correct and send back a response

Is it wrong to think in this way ?

> PS: I want to do that because I want my app just to communicate only
>   using RESTful API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this documentation: [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/)

Look for "Sign in with email / password" for example on how to sign in , Firebase answer with an `ID_TOKEN` that you have to provide when you  issue HTTP REST queries.